# jQuery :invalid HTML 5 form with required select element

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I've been using `$('select[required]').is(':invalid')` if the browser supports the pattern attribute `if(Modernizr.input.pattern) {}`, and it works fine in Firefox 4-7, but Chrome and Safari are both having issues.

All other validations work fine, its just required select menus i.e. `<select required><option></option></select>`

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbCbt/. Basically, you select a drop down item, and its meant to validate it.

In firefox, selecting 'test' will say its valid. Selecting 'please select' will says its invalid.

In Safari/Chrome, selecting 'test' will say invalid, then selecting 'please select' will make it it VALID. Selecting test again will make it invalid. From there, select test2 and it will be VALID, then select test again, and it will be valid this time.

I assume its a jQuery thing, because the browser is recognising its valid from the CSS...

Thoughts?  I realise there isn't really any official support for the function (not in the jquery kb), but I'm hoping there's another way around it. I have degraded validation checking for older browsers so maybe I should just drop back to that for webkit?

Comment: required='required' is the standard syntax, but I tried that in your example ... doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Hmm, thanks didn't think of that. Pity it didn't work either way though... The W3C Spec for required uses `<input id="username" type=email required name=un>` as an example, so that's why I thought to just use `required`.

Comment: Just had a thought... maybe it's a timing issue. I'll try that.

Comment: Yep, that's the ticket. The change() event fires before the HTML5/CSS validation occurs. Just put alert('here'); in front of the test, and you can see that the SELECT is still red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a Safari bug. The validator is correct, but only the second time it is called. When you call is(':invalid'), it's returning the previous validation.

I tried forking your example, and calling (this.validity()), but it returns the same thing. Only the CSS is accurate!

I'm stumped at how to easily get this - the DOM doesn't return the value of the CSS. I tried checking the $(this).css('border') and this.style.borderColor to get a result, no dice.

**UPDATE**
The change() event is firing before any validation has happened. Putting an alert('here'); in front of your .is(':invalid'); shows that the element is still "red" from the invalid CSS attribute.

If you attempt the validation after an elapsed time, via
    window.setTimeout(doValidateTest(this),10)
or somesuch, then it will likely return correctly.

Comment: Amazing! So that must mean that firefox runs the validation before the change event then? Thanks a lot for that!