# Select, null option select, difference in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, select, null, default

The code is below and at http://jsfiddle.net/eCubeH/utBEs/1/

The select is required. So selecting the first empty string value option should make it invalid.

I use jquery condition: ($(myChangeSelector + ":invalid").length > 0) to identify the invalid state. Firefox 15 returns a value of 1 correctly to show it is invalid. Chrome 21 returns 0 and then continues to behave inconsistently.

Been breaking my head on this, is this a Chrome bug or something I am missing?

----- the code -----

```
<select id="selDisbLocation" required="" tabindex="3">
    <option value="" >-</option>
    <option value="0" selected>Center</option>
    <option value="1" >Office</option>
</select>​

$(function() {
    $("select").live(
    "change",
    function(event) {
       myChangeSelector = "#" + event.target.id;
       alert(myChangeSelector);
       alert($(myChangeSelector).val());
       alert("Invalid Length: " + $(myChangeSelector + ":invalid").length);
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:invalid, the CSS pseudo-class `:invalid` only apply to `<input>` and `<form>` elements. That may be the cause of your unexpected results.

I would suggest invalidating the `<select>` by value or index instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's the route I will have to take it seems. I see a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815951/jquery-invalid-html-5-form-with-required-select-element. I tried .is(':invalid') also, which gives the same error in Chrome, works in FF.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably due to how the different browsers implemented the feature. Because `<select>` isn't officially supported, it's possible that some browsers don't even have an unofficial implementation for that element.