# Select an invalid HTML5 input with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input, validation, selector

Since the CSS `:invalid` selector is the default value for the inputs, I need to use jQuery to change the invalid input's style only when the user makes a change on an input and is still invalid. I have tried many things, but it seems like the `:invalid` selector is not available in jQuery.

This:

```
$("#formulaire input").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":invalid")) {
        $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
    }
})
```

doesn't work. I also tried selecting the invalid inputs in the begning:

```
$("#formulaire input:invalid").change(function () {
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
})
```

But that doesn't work either.

Hopefully you will be able to help me :).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TWQgN/

Comment: Please construct a jsFiddle demo and also see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7816160/594235

Comment: Thanks, but why a jsFiddle? It's just a basic form...Also I already read this thread and it did not help me.

Comment: Since jQuery doesn't have built-in validation, it can't tell which elements are valid and invalid. Why not use regular CSS?

Comment: You want help from other people, right?  So you use a jsFiddle to exactly demonstrate the issue.  (We also can't see your HTML).

Comment: @Barmar, `:invalid` is part of HTML5.

Comment: Because using the CSS selector :invalid will put all my inputs with a red background directly at load, since all the inputs are invalid by default (maybe because I put a required)

Comment: @Sparky Does JS provide an API for jQuery to ask the browser if an input element is valid? If not, how is jQuery supposed to support that selector, even if it's part of HTML5?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TWQgN/

Comment: @Barmar, I did not mean to imply this was supposed to work... I merely stated where it's coming from.  Yes, `:invalid` is not a jQuery selector.

Comment: Seems there is an API: element.validity.

Answer (score 5):

Selectors supported by jQuery are listed [on the selectors API page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). The `:invalid` pseudo-class is not listed there as of jQuery 1.9.0, so doesn't appear to be supported. Unless and until that selector is supported, you can access the DOM object and use its input validity API. For example:

```
$("#formulaire input").change(function() {
    if (Boolean($(this)[0].checkValidity) && (! $(this)[0].checkValidity())) {
        $(this).css("backgroundColor", "red");
    }
});
```

`$(this)[0]` returns the underlying [DOM HTMLInputElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text) object. The `checkValidity()` method will return false if the input element is invalid. (And I put in the test `Boolean($(this)[0].checkValidity)` just so that you do not get an exception if this code is run on an older browser that doesn't support HTML input validation.)

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is equivalent to `this` and `Boolean()` isn't necessary. So the `if` condition could be reduced to `this.checkValidity && !this.checkValidity()`

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this issue today and have been having a hard time figuring out how to use Jquery for testing and acting on :invalid form fields. I run ajax on this form so the user can submit a review and not have to leave the page they are on. so I make sure that the form fields are all valid and completed if they are required using html5 require methods and pattern matching. Then in jquery, I found that it will count the number of fields I have that are invalid with the following situation:

```
$('.containerClass').on('click', '#button', function(){
    var valid = $(this).closest('#form').find('input:invalid').length;
    if(valid > 0){
        alert("Almost there! Please finish the last " + valid + " required fields to complete your review");
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({ 
                //do stuff 
            });
        }
});
```