# jQuery support ":invalid" selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I get the following console message:

```
[16:04:01.292] Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: invalid @ http://localhost:8080/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js:4
```

When I try something like:

`if( $(e.target).is(':invalid') ){ ... }`

How do I fix this?

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4g99/ - try changing the jQuery version (stops working after 1.9)

Comment: custom validators are not suppored after jquery 1.8

Comment: This might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815951/jquery-invalid-html-5-form-with-required-select-element

Comment: According to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:invalid , this selector exists.

Comment: That's CSS not javascript, and jQuery recreates some CSS pseudo-selectors as expressions for your convience, this is not one of those selectors

Comment: Perhaps you need to use it through `querySelectorAll`, since it's a CSS selector, but not a jQuery selector

Comment: pseudo selectors are'nt actual elements in the DOM, so I doubt you can target them at all with `querySelector`, but I'm not sure ?

Comment: If you're going to use selectors that are still in working-draft and not a recommendation, you might as well ditch jQuery and simply use `HTMLElement#querySelectorAll`

Comment: Can't use "querySelector" according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: There are pseudo-classes (which filter existing elements) and pseudo-elements (which don't exist in the DOM). `:invalid` seems to be the former.

Comment: @jldupont that document doesn't seem to indicate QSA doesn't support pseudo-classes, only there's a bug concerning pseudo-_elements_ (`::after`, `::before`) in the selector.

Comment: @JanDvorak - all one has to do is test it -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qAmKa/), and it does indeed work just fine, so you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @adeneo doesn't work on Firefox 19

Comment: @adeneo Same here, FF 20 - I see `(an empty string)` in my console

Comment: This is definitely a 1.9 issue. If you test this - http://jsfiddle.net/L4g99/ - with different jQuery versions, it stops working with 1.9. I'm not sure if that was obvious or not

Comment: @adeneo Nevermind. It's because at least in FF, the `<form>` is the first `:invalid` element.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `querySelectorAll` as suggested by @JanDvorak (and his answer should be accepted for thinking of that), you can write your own expression, making `.is(':invalid')` valid ?

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    invalid : function(elem, index, match){
        var invalids = document.querySelectorAll(':invalid'),
            result = false,
            len = invalids.length;

        if (len) {
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if (elem === invalids[i]) {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

now you can do :

```
if( $(e.target).is(':invalid') ){ ... }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qAmKa/2/)

Comment: sorry; took me a while to write my answer.

Comment: Yours is better. Upvoting.

Comment: Not woking in IE<10. Bad Syntax.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(':invalid')` is giving me "Syntax error" under IE9, even though I've used `X-UA-Compatible IE=Edge` - any suggestions?

Comment: IE9 does not support HTML5 form validation at all, hence the `:invalid` selector doesn't work -> http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Answer (score 13):

`:invalid` is, indeed, not a valid jQuery selector (pseudoclass).

According to [the link you posted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:invalid), however, it is a valid CSS selector (not supported in IE<10).

[A fiddle by Adeneo](http://jsfiddle.net/qAmKa/) shows that, as suspected, while it doesn't work in jQuery, it can be used via the native `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` methods. So, while this doesn't work:

```
if($(e.target).is(":invalid"))  //SyntaxError
```

This does (except in IE<10):

```
if(~[].indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(":invalid"),e.target))
```

This should work as well (in the future or after the neccessary shimming; see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector)):

```
if(e.target.matches(":invalid"))
```

Comment: +1, I was'nt sure wether or not to post an answer, as this should go to you. I would never have thought the native querySelector would work for this.

Comment: @adeneo it was you who wrote the fiddle

Comment: Yeah, but that was mostly copy/paste from MDN. Here on SO there ***is*** room for the idea guy !

Comment: @adeneo you also showed how to extend jQuery with custom pseudo-classes

Comment: I've confirmed the above, but am surprised that this works: `$(':invaild')` -- prints all invalid elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use element's `validity` attribute (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)).

Now combining it with @adeneo's idea:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    invalid : function(elem, index, match){
        return elem.validity !== undefined && elem.validity.valid === false;
    },

    valid : function(elem, index, match){
        return elem.validity !== undefined && elem.validity.valid === true;
    }


});
```