# HTML5: Is there any way to show error bubble popup for input fields?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a form with `HTML5` features. I  am customized error messages using `setCustomValidity` function . But most of the input fields need to show the error message `onfocusout` event. I did this code for achieve this.

```
$("form").bind("change" , function(e){
    var ele = e.target;
    if(field.is(":invalid")){
        ele.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
    }else{
        ele.setCustomValidity('');
    }
});
```

[image]

But , I don't know how to open the bubble popup here.

Comment: I didn't understand your question very well. Are you trying to run that code when the user "leave" the input (ie: `blur`` event)?

Comment: @Uby , I attached the image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820780/jquery-support-invalid-selector

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is but you will need to `checkValidity()` on the form and then submit it if it is false.  It's not the nicest code.

```
if(!$('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
  $('form').submit();
}
```

Keep in mind not all browsers support form validation.  I would personally leave the validation as the browsers have it as that is what the users will be used to.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use javascript library for triggering the validations and also you can set custom messages for validation.

Reference link : [Link](http://34codefactory.blogspot.in/2018/01/create-custom-javascript-validation.html)

Using this you can trigger validation message on `onfocusout`

Download  CSS and JS from the above link and add into your HTML page. Add validation rules based on your requirement.

```
<input type="text" name="emp_code" id="emp_code" data-rule="emp_code|required">
```

Here `required` is predefined rule and `emp_code` is custom rule which is created by user.

Last step is to initialize the library.

```
<script>
// #form is id of form
new Validator(document.querySelector('#form'), function(err, res) {
   return res;
}
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @AsifAli72090 Thank you.