# JQuery - How to test if an input element has the valid or invalid pseudo-class applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you test if an input element has the CSS3 :valid or :invalid pseudo-class applied to it with jQuery?  I would like to test if the form element passed the CSS validation before enabling a submit button.

Things I tried already that did not work:

```
if($("#el").is(":valid")) {
    //...
}

if($("#el:valid").length == 0) {
    //...
}

$("#el").attr("valid")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820780/jquery-support-invalid-selector

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? Seems to not work for recent jQuery version only in 1.9.x due to a bug i guess

Comment: Currently using jQuery version 1.9.1, perhaps I could upgrade.

Comment: Ya, upgrading to 1.10.x will fix this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After upgrading to jquery 1.10.2, I can confirm that using the :valid selector now works as expected.

```
if($("#el").is(":valid")) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work with webkit pseudoclasses.

Comment: is this possible with vanilla JS?

Answer (score 2):

If your Jquery version is older than 1.10.2, you can manage it this way:

```
if ($('#subscriberNumTb:valid').length > 0) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: jQuery 3.5.0 throws error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: valid"

Comment: use `:invalid` instead and it should work

Answer (score 1):

For anybody wanting to know how to do it with vanilla JS.

```
inputEle.reportValidity() // `true` if valid, `false` otherwise
```