# :invalid and :required CSS pseudo-classes don't work with jQuery traversing methods when selector matches multiple form elements

Tags: jquery, forms, pseudo-class, jquery-traversing

**HTML**

```
<input required>
<input required>
<input required>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/*
// Add script for noted :invalid check to work
// :required can also be made to work by modifying script, i.e. changing "invalid" to "required" where noted
// Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821264/2171842
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    invalid : function(elem, index, match){ // modify pseudo-class here
        var invalids = document.querySelectorAll(':invalid'), // modify pseudo-class here
            result = false,
            len = invalids.length;

        if (len) {
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                if (elem === invalids[i]) {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
});
*/
$(document).ready(function(){
  // works
  console.log("number of invalid elements: "+$(":invalid").length); // selector matches multiple elements
  console.log("is first element invalid? "+$("input:first").is(":invalid")); // selector matches one element
  console.log("is at least one element enabled? "+$("input").is(":enabled")); // selector matches multiple elements
  // fails without additional script, :required also fails
  console.log("is at least one element invalid? "+$("input").is(":invalid")) // selector matches multiple elements
  console.log("number of invalid elements: "+$("input:first").siblings(":invalid").andSelf(":invalid").length) // selector (siblings(":invalid")) matches multiple elements
});
```

Console error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: invalid`. Follow comments in code to navigate problem. Is this a bug or just an unsupported feature in jQuery?

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/cbqdp43s/

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a bug or just an unsupported feature in jQuery?

Unsupported features. `:invalid` , `:required` are not a jQuery extended selectors . See [Category: jQuery Extensions](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/)

Though  [Has Attribute Selector [name]](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) `$("[required]")` should return expected results for element having `required` attribute.

See also [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)

> The `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class represents any `<input>` or `<form>`
>   element whose content fails to validate according to the input's type
>   setting.

Comment: `:invalid` and `:required` are CSS3 selectors so they don't need to be added as jQuery extended selectors

Comment: @JairoContreras What is expected result ?

Comment: Also, the :invalid selector selects form elements with a value that does not validate according to the element's settings. This includes elements other than input, such as select and textarea. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_invalid.asp.

Comment: @JairoContreras  If add `value` attribute to `input` elements and include a value at that attribute property, `$(":invalid").length` should return `0` https://jsfiddle.net/cbqdp43s/11/ . What is expected result of using `:invalid` selector ?

Comment: see fiddle and console: if you add script by removing the comment marks, is at least one element invalid? true and number of invalid elements: 3

Comment: _" if you add script by removing the comment marks, is at least one element invalid? true and number of invalid elements: 2"_ ? Not following ? What is requirement ? Check if at least one `input` element is invalid ?

Comment: a required input that is blank is invalid, just as an input type=email with an invalid email is invalid

Comment: _"a required input that is blank is invalid, just as an input type=email with an invalid email is invalid"_ Yes. Not certain what requirement of Question is ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100306/discussion-between-jairo-contreras-and-guest271314).