# JQuery how to set :invalid to true on a <select> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

```
$("#select_id").is(':invalid')
```

> false

how do I set it to true?

```
$("#select_id").addClass(':invalid');
$("#select_id").prop('invalid',true)
```

does not work :(

Comment: you cannot set pseudoclass ```invalid``` from js/jquery, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709088/invalid-and-required-css-pseudo-classes-dont-work-with-jquery-traversing-meth

Comment: Maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128882/set-input-as-invalid/18129355

Answer (score -1):

**you can do in this way**

var select=!$("#select_id").is(':invalid');

Now $("#select_id").is(':invalid') return false but this **!** will make it to true