# Validating Bootstrap form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form and I am basically trying to loop through all input fields, check if they have a `required` class and their value is `null`, if so add some CSS as an error indicator. For some reason the `if` statement is not working.

My code is:

```
$("#orderForm").on("submit", function(e) {
var formInputFields = $(".form-control")
formInputFields.each(function(i) {
  if (formInputFields[i].hasClass("required") && formInputFields[i].val() === "null") {
    e.preventDefault();
    formInputFields.css("border", "2px solid #741e4f");
  }
});
```

});

HTML is along these lines, but longer, same structure though, the `form-group` div is repeated:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="orderForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Lorem</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select name="" id="" class="form-control required">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="lorem">lorem</option>
                  <option value="ipsun">ipsun</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: add a semicolon `var formInputFields = $(".form-control");`

Comment: @ Hi JSamarjiev, why do you not try - JS Validator for form validation. Check out this link:: http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel - http://jqueryvalidation.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code threw error when you say `formInputFields[i].hasClass` because `formInputFields` was a **`jquery object`** but not `formInputFields[i]`. Since you were using `$.each`, the 2nd parameter would have given you current element and instead of `formInputFields[i]`, you could just use that 2nd parameter. Also, when you say `cur.val()==="null"` it will be strong comparison between left and right i.e. both should match by `value` and `type` which always failed here. So just check the `length` of `val` and if it is **`0`** that will be **`invalid element`**. Below are the changes I've made. Check and it and let me know if you face any issues.

```js
$("#orderForm").on("submit", function(e) {
  var formInputFields = $(".form-control")
  formInputFields.each(function(i, v) {
    var cur = $(v);
    if (cur.hasClass("required") && !(cur.val().length)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      cur.css("border", "2px solid #741e4f");
    }
    else
      cur.css("border", "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-horizontal" id="orderForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Lorem</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select name="" id="" class="form-control required">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="lorem">lorem</option>
        <option value="ipsun">ipsun</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the thinking behind `cur` syntactically?

Comment: I would expand it as **current**... :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when an input is required add [required as an attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) rather than a class.

`<input type="text" id="foo" placeholder="bar" value="" required>`

Then you will be able to get any required inputs currently missing values using:

`var list_of_invalid_inputs = document.querySelectorAll('*:invalid');`

or if you must use jquery [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820780/jquery-support-invalid-selector).

The same selector works in css too:

`input:invalid { border: 2px solid #741e4f; }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **$(this)** instead of **formInputFields[i].hasClass...** as you need the object to verify if it has the "required" class or not and if it has value or not, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#orderForm").on("submit", function(e){
        var formInputFields = $(".form-control");
    formInputFields.each(function(i) {
        if($(this).hasClass("required") && $.trim($(this).val()) === ""){
        e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css("border", "2px solid #741e4f");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thonyrg/d529y82g/)