# Remove Parent Class if Input Field is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have a question.
How can I check if an input field is filled with text and remove a div class on it?

I've already tried it but it doesn't worked....

```js
 $('.form-control-login input').blur(function(){
    if( !$(this).val() ) 
          $(this).parent().removeClass('is-empty');
    
});
```

```css
.is-empty {
  color:red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
 <label class="control-label">Your Email</label>
 <input class="form-control-login" name="login" autocomplete="username">
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Gamernamer/wwd8x63p/2/

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly your selector is incorrect. The `.form-control-login` element *is* the `input`, so you don't need that.

To fix the issue use the `input` event instead of `blur`, so that the class will be updated as the user type. You can then set the class on the parent element in a one-liner using `toggleClass()`, like this:

```js
$('.form-control-login').on('input', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('is-empty', this.value.trim().length == 0);
});
```

```css
.is-empty {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
  <label class="control-label">Your Email</label>
  <input class="form-control-login" name="login" autocomplete="username">
</div>
```

Comment: @vicnoob No, as `.form-control-login input` is looking for an `input` within an `input`, which cannot be correct.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'd also suggest you add a `type` attribute to the input. If username's are always email addresses `type="email"` would work best for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh my mistake i didn't realize that i also remove the input in selector of my solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Searching for 1 1/2 hour now and doesn't found something which worked for me... What script should I add If i want to add/toggle a class to the parent dif if the type in the field is invalid?

Comment: Depends on how you're determining the field is invalid. `addClass()` or `removeClass()` would seem to fit though

Comment: Thanks.. already thought about add(class) or remove class() but the point which I doesn't know is how i can define :invalid in the script... thought about something like : 

$('.form-control-login').on('input', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('login-error', this.hasClass(:invalid);
});

-> So If the Class is invalid, addClass() to parent...

Comment: jQuery doesn't have an `:invalid` selector, so that won't work. You will need to manually check the value to see if it matches your requirements. You can add support for `:invalid` if you prefer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820780/jquery-support-invalid-selector

Comment: Thanks, that helped me alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.form-control-login').blur(function() {
     if ($(this).val())
       $(this).parent().removeClass('is-empty');

   });
 })
```

You should check if ($(this).val()) is not empty, then remove the class, not in the reverse way.

Comment: This doesn't add the class when you have a value in the field and remove it.

Comment: Yes I think his idea is check when the input is blur

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will achieve your requirement

- Give $('.form-control-login') instead of  $('.form-control-login input
- use if( $(this).val() ) instead of if( !$(this).val() )

```js
$('.form-control-login').blur(function(){
    console.log("dd");
    if( $(this).val() ) 
          $(this).parent().removeClass('is-empty');
    
});
```

```css
.is-empty {
  color:red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
 <label class="control-label">Your Email</label>
 <input class="form-control-login" name="login" autocomplete="username">
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't add the class when you have a value in the field and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.form-control-login').blur(function()
{

    if( $(this).val() != '' ) {

          $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('is-empty');
    }
else {
$(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('is-empty');
}
});
```

```css
.is-empty {
  color:red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
 <label class="control-label">Your Email</label>
 <input class="form-control-login" name="login" autocomplete="username">
 </div>
```

```js
$('.form-control-login').blur(function()
{

    if( $(this).val() != '' ) {

          $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('is-empty');
    }
});
```

```css
.is-empty {
  color:red;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
 <label class="control-label">Your Email</label>
 <input class="form-control-login" name="login" autocomplete="username">
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't add the class when you have a value in the field and remove it.